# Disable Copy/Paste/Share menu but keep text selectable

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I already know about user-select: none css rule, but it doesn’t help me with my problem.

The thing is I have my own custom menu that appears when I long press or select text in my paragraphs, however the android default menu is displayed on top of my own and hinders the user experience.

I know there is a cordova plugin that already takes care of the issue in iOS but I couldn’t find one for android.

I want to remain able to select my text, with my own custom options on top of that but disable the default android menu. Please help.

Comment: what do you mean by android menu? is it the cut, copy, paste one?